# Opening all ports on localhost for internal communication

Tags: networking, iptables

Currently, I have to allow each and every port I want to connect from & to localhost (`iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT`), which is a) a little bit annoying each time, and b) often impossible with services which change their local port.

I'm testing this with `netcat` on debian:

```
nc -vv -l -s 127.0.0.1 -p 8888
```

is listening on the 127.0.0.1 interface at port 8888. Trying to connect

```
nc 127.0.0.1 8888
```

results in a connection refused, until I manually add the rule above.
How can I make this work?

I tried to allow all traffic on the loopback interface, to no avail:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

and also to allow everything from `127.0.0.1`:

```
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

Shouldn't that work, since `netstat` is listing it as coming from 127.0.0.1:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15338/nc
```

Here are my current rules:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Thu Jan 25 08:01:28 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jan 25 08:01:28 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Thu Jan 25 08:01:28 2018
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:port-scan - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2368 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 9987 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1666 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/min --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i wintap0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A port-scan -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK RST -m limit --limit 1/sec -j RETURN
-A port-scan -j DROP
```

**Note: I obviously, don't want the ports visible to the outside world, only internally.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly this line:

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

As it comes before your rules that allow traffic to `lo` and has no filter, the last four rules are never looked at:

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
```

You don't have to worry about people being able to connect to a service that is listening only the `lo` interface (127.0.0.1/8): that is an internal-only interface.

Answer (score 3):

As opposed to adding the line pesistently by appending:

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Try adding the line persistently by inputting:

```
-I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-I OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

This will position the rule at the front of the INPUT chain as opposed to the end. The

```
 -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

is blocking the rule from being read.